# Multilingual Site information field with hook_form_alter

Tags: i18n-l10n, forms

I have added a field to my site information settings page by using hook_form_alter:

```
function site_fields_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'system_site_information_settings') {
 $form['site_information']['site_fields_slogan2'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Slogan 2'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('slogan2', TRUE),
 );
 $form['#submit'][] = 'site_fields_form_submit';
 }
}
```

...but the field doesn't appear on the multilingual variables page to be able to translate it. I've tried adding '#localize' => TRUE but this doesn't seem to work. Ay ideas?